# PNG when Save file Size increased

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have just reduced the size of a png from 512 x512 to 256 x 256px and the file size has gone from 100kb to 165kb? Why is this happening and more important how can I reduce file size below 100kb after resize?

Comment: A screen shot of the settings/process you are using to save your image would help narrow it down, but I think that Jalal is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have changed the bits of the png, it sounds like your .png format was 8bits and you have turned it to 24bits